# Multilevel grouping in a single column - ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have been trying to add a multiplevel grouping in the job field column as shown below (sample excel sheet template), Column Job has job code and then visit dates grouped by job code. Is there any way to achieve to this in SSRS 2008 r2?

It works if i add another group column VisitDates and set the toogle item property to column Job but i need to show the visit date below the job code number.

**Required**

[image]

**Achieved so far;**

[image]

Comment: What is your issue? Do you need Visit Date be in the same column than job code? That is how it appears in your report.

Comment: attached screen shot is a sample excel sheet. Yes i want visit Date to be shown in the same column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a basic example you have to adjust it to your requeriment.

1. Add a new tablix and set the `DataSetName` property to the dataset you are using.
2. In the `Row Groups` pane right click `Details` group select `Add Group` / `Parent Group...` and use these settings:

[image]

3. Delete the created column in the previous step, leaving only the group.

[image]

4. Delete the first row, and use the Job Code field in the remaining first row and in the first column.

`=Fields!Job_Code.Value`

5.In the below cell use Visit Date value:

[image]

6. Set toggle in the `Visit Date` row as below, replace Textbox297 by the name of the Textbox where Job Code is placed:

[image]

It should produce:

Collapsed

[image]

Expanded

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated my question with the screen shot of what i achieved so far.

Comment: @user1263981, First add a Visit Date then add Job Code as parent group as mentioned in step 2 in my answer. Once you have the setup for Job Code you can add additional groups.